# AJAX/PHP - Lagtime in Creating SQL Table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have a simple HTML form:

```js
var submitForm=function() {
    var i={};
 i[0]=$('#sname').val();
 var json=JSON.stringify(i);
    $.ajax({
      url: './form.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {data: json},
      success: function() {
        alert('Section Added.');
      }
    });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="sname">
<button onClick="submitForm()">submit</button>
```

In PHP, I take this value and insert it into a database, such as:

```
    $data=json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
    $section=$data[0];
    include './sql/write-section.php';
    $sql="CREATE TABLE ".$section." (revdate varchar(250), title varchar(250), descrip varchar(255), permissions varchar(99999), file varchar(255))";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $conn->close();
```

The issue is, that the table isn't being created.  Initially, I thought it was an issue in my code, however if I were to replace line 2 in the PHP with just `$section="test";`, it works fine.

Additionally, if I add in some lines between the POST and SQL query, it *sometimes* works.

It is a very odd behavior and I am thinking there is some sort of async or lag issue between JS/PHP/SQL.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What does $data output? E.g `var_dump($data)`

Comment: Just gave it a try by simply using var_dump($data) and it returned only the value of "sname" (HTML input ID).  Additionally, when outputting $data[0], it outputs the value of "sname", making me believe it is not a HTML/JS issue, but rather a PHP/SQL one.  I did some error checking and nothing reported.

Comment: Do you see anything if you add `or die($conn->error)` after `$conn->query($sql)`?

Comment: Why are you using JSON? Why not just `{data: i}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after days of investigation and some annoyance, I found the issue, and it's really stupid.

The query I have doesn't allow for spaces (or at least in the SQL version I'm using I can't use spaces).  So when trying I was trying a few different things like:

- Test Section
- 123
- Test Section 1

Well, the reason why it worked once and never again is best for that one time it worked I put in "Test" for the table name.

I am re-structuring the script to allow spaces.